# what is the most negative fraction that can be represented by a n bit binary number in 2's complement?

Tags: cpu-architecture, twos-complement, fixed-point

I am reading computer architecture by Carl Hamacher. The following lines are confusing me

> If we use a 32-bit binary number to represent a signed integer in 2's complement then the range of values that can be represented is `-2^31 to 2^31 - 1`. //fine
>
> The same 32-bit patterns can be interpreted as fractions in the range `-1 to +1 - 2^-31` if we assume that the implied binary point is just to the right of the sign bit.

I don't understand how the range has been calculated for the fraction. I myself calculated the range for positive fractions with the highest fraction being `2^31-1`. But I am unable to calculate the lowest value (mentioned as -1).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shifting the binary point is tantamount to dividing by a power of two. So if we shift the binary point 31 positions, we are effectively representing fractions whose denominators are 2<sup>31</sup> and whise numerators are the unshifted integers. Thus the range becomes -2<sup>31</sup>/2<sup>31</sup> to (2<sup>31</sup>-1)/2<sup>31</sup>, which is -1 to 1-2<sup>-31</sup>.

Another way to look at it: In 2's complement integer representation, the bit positions have weights (left to right) of -2<sup>31</sup>, 2<sup>30</sup>, 2<sup>29</sup>, …, 2<sup>0</sup> (where only the first weight is negative). Shifting the binary point to just after the high-order (and negated) bit -- "the sign bit" -- makes rhe weights -2<sup>0</sup>, 2<sup>-1</sup>, 2<sup>-2</sup>, …, 2<sup>-31</sup> (again, only the first weight is negative). Again, it's clear that the "most negative" is 100…0, which has the value -1, the weight for the only one-bit

Comment: Thanks a lot . Your first reason was sufficient . Your second reason taught me another thing . Previously to calculate the the value of 1000 in 2's complement I used to find the 2's complement of 1000 (which would be a positive) =+8 .I would then flip the sign to get the value of 1000 . It took so long . But now i know how to find it directly by assigning the most significant bit a negative weight . Thanks to you.